# Проблема с парсером и pupeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, puppeteer

Всем привет . Решил недавно переписать парсер для бота . Начал переписывать и тут вылезает одна гадкая ошибка . Переменная page объявляется локально так как там используется другая асинхронная переменная . Другие функции требуют глобального объявления этой переменной но я не могу . Помогите . Вот код:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"),
      cheerio   = require("cheerio"),
      chalk     = require("chalk");
    

let page;

async function main(title){
    try{
    let r = await search(title);
    console.log(r)
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    }catch{
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    if (browser) {
        await browser.close();
    }
}
async function search(title){
    const [ librariusBooks, labirintBooks ] = await Promise.all([
        librSearch(title),
        labirSearch(title)
    ]);
    
    return { librariusBooks, labirintBooks };
}
async function librSearch(title){
    const url = `https://librarius.md/ru/search?search=${title}`
    await page.goto(url);
    const content = await page.content()
    const $ = cheerio.load(content)
    let books = await librParser($, title)
    return books;
}

async function librParser($, title){
    $('.book__title').slice(4, 9).each((idx, elem) => {
        let booksTitles = [];
        let LibrBookName = $(elem).text();
        let LibrTitle = LibrBookName.toLowerCase();
        if(LibrTitle.includes(title)){
            booksTitles.push({BookName: LibrTitle, id: idx});
        }
    })
    return booksTitles;
}
main("Ведьмак");
```

Может я где-то затупок но я просто редко использую асинхроные функции

Comment: А зачем cheerio, когда есть  puppeteer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вы определяете `page` уже после того, как пытаетесь её использовать в цепочке вызовов `search()` - `librSearch()`. Попробуйте запустить браузер и определить `page` до первого вызова из цепочки. Вдобавок, вместо создания глобальной переменной, вы можете передавать `page` в аргументах функций из цепочки.

Comment: спасибо . Надо было просто передавать page в функции и всё